# UPDATE table using join and MAX function

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables t1 & t2

**Table t1**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   RequestID       dateCreated               dateSolProvided   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 100         4/1/2015 11:31:36 AM         4/1/2015 11:04:04 AM |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here dateSolProvided is supposed be greater than dateCreated.

**Table t2**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| RequestID    RequestDetailID         SolutionProvidedDate |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 100            123456                4/1/2015 11:04:04 AM |
| 100            678910                4/1/2015 11:41:56 AM |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now my problem is, I have to update **Table t1 --> dateSolProvided** based on the **maximum** value of **SolutionProvidedDate of Table t2**

So the solution should be (for table t1) :

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   RequestID       dateCreated               dateSolProvided   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 100         4/1/2015 11:31:36 AM         4/1/2015 11:41:56 AM |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How to update these two tables using joins and using MAX function together?

Comment: You should look up the `Merge` method in t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET dateSolProvided = ( SELECT TOP 1 SolutionProvidedDate
                            FROM Table2
                            WHERE RequestID = t1.RequestID
                            ORDER BY SolutionProvidedDate DESC
                          )
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE dateSolProvided < dateCreated
```